# error when calling a script in powershell created using CreateFile ()

Tags: powershell, createfile

there is an error when creating .ps1 and calling the script in powershell, it gives an error

```
const TCHAR VpnConnectionName[] = (L"C:\\Users\\illia\\\Desktop\\temp.ps1");
const TCHAR BufferStn[] = L"cd\\";
DWORD BYTES = NULL;
        
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(VpnConnectionName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
    {
        std::cout << "Console:INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE" << std::endl;
    }
    WriteFile(hFile, &BufferStn, sizeof(BufferStn), &BYTES, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
```

when trying calls in powershell:

[image: Error powershell]

Comment: `TCHAR` = UTF16 - you need to [write a BOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-byte-order-marks) to the lowest offset of the file, otherwise it's indistinguishable from an ASCII-encoded file containing `c\0d\0\\\0`

Comment: I already solved the problem by using char * instead of THCAR

Comment: That will work too (just be aware you won't be able to use Unicode characters)